# Handsontable max. rows to post with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, json, post, handsontable

I use Handontable and AJAX to POST the entire table as JSON to a php script which saves the data in a database. Works great!

But the max number of rows is 334. If I try to add more rows it will stop at row 334. If I count the rows in the JSON object it gives me correct number but if I count the number of rows server side in the $_POST variable it gives me 334.

```
var data = {"data":$('#spreadsheet').handsontable('getData')};
alert(data.data.length);
```

Returns correct number.

```
Log::info(count(Input::get('data')));
```

Server side returns max. 334.

Firebug says: Size limit of post response was reached.

But if I add more columns to the table the limit is still 334. So it's not so much the size in Bytes but more acutaly the number of rows.

Anymore a clue whats happening and how to solve it?

Comment: How many columns does your 334-row table have? What is max_input_vars configured as in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Javascript:**

```
var _data = handsontable.getData();

$.ajax({
   data: {"data":JSON.stringify(_data)},
   .
   .
   .
});
```

**PHP:**

```
$data=isset($_POST['data'])?$_POST['data']:"";

$temp_data = str_replace('\\', "",$data);

$data=json_decode($data,true);

vardump($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Increasing max_input_vars in your server php.ini file.

I was with the same problem.